# What is the word in majiang equivalent to suits in cards?

Tags: vocabulary

With playing cards with French faces, ♣♠♥♦ are collectively called *suits* in English, *Farben* (*"colours"*) in German.

With majiang tiles, what is the collective noun in Chinese for 饼、条、万, a property of 序数牌?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The measure word for 饼、条、万 is called `门`, which literally means 'department; division; faction'.

Example usage:

> ……序数牌……分“筒子/饼”、“索子/条”、“万子/万”三**门**，每**门**有序数从一至九的牌各四张。(from [wikipedia](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%BA%BB%E5%B0%86))

An alternative measure word is `(花)色`, which literally means color/pattern. 色 is also widely used.

When talking about the abstract concept of 'suit' in Mahjong, per my own experience `门` is more common, although `色` is perfectly fine too. There might be regional differences though.

When it comes to specific Mahjong terminologies like `清一色` or `一色三步高`, those are set phrases in which 色 should not be replaced by 门.

Comment: Eh, you are obviously not a majiang player. 清一色 (”flush”), 字一色 and 混一色 are common terms, but I have actually never ever heard something like 清一门 in this context…

Comment: @倪阔乐 Of course I know 清一色, but that's not what the OP was asking. The question is about the name of the concept/measure word for 饼、条、万. I'll update the answer to clarify.

Comment: No, OP is not asking for the ”measure word”, but what the term for a suit is. 色 is the answer: 纸牌开始共有60张，分为文钱、索子、万贯三种花色，其三色都是一至九各两张 http://baike.baidu.com/subview/10590/4947520.htm

Comment: @倪阔乐 Why don't you improve your own answer to be better than NS.X.'s if you disagree with his.

Comment: @倪阔乐 Both 门 and 色 are right translation for 'suit' and I can find plenty of references that use 门, even in your Baidu link (under 四川麻将 section: 麻将牌只有筒、条、万三门；缺门可胡). You made good point though for the set phrases like 清一色, and I've updated my answer to reflect that.